# Small JavaScript Hover Slider Image Gallery Not Working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse

I recently found the perfect mini-script for the pictures section of the site I've been working on non-stop for the last half year.  I had it working but apparently in Firefox it doesn't want to play nice.  What's even odder is I've played with it a bit; all my references are fine, but the thing won't do what I say anymore.  Another oddity is I searched Google for some of the code, found it again (to examine it), and wouldn't you know: that incarnation runs perfectly on WebKit and even ran flawlessly on Firefox!  I am about to pull my hair out, so, any help is appreciated.  By the way, the script in question gets dynamically loaded towards the end of the DIV.  My site (pictures section): http://www.elemovements.com/pictures and the replica: http://www.gmcbryde.com/.  Here is the code, as well, just for good measure (which you can find unminified at http://el.x10.mx/js/logic/pictures.js [you need only concern yourself with the first 40-50 lines or so]):

```js
if ( $('div.highslide-gallery').length ) {

    $( function() {

        var $Div = $('div.highslide-gallery'),
            $Ul = $('ul.horiz-list'),
            $UlPadding = 0;

        $Ul.width(9000);
        $Div.width( $Div.parent().parent().width() - 26 );

        var $DivWidth = $Div.width();

        $Div.css( {overflow: 'hidden'} );

        var lastLi = $Ul.find('li:last-child');

        $Div.mousemove(function(e){

            var $UlWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + $UlPadding; 

            var left = (e.pageX - $Div.offset().left) * ($UlWidth-$DivWidth) / $DivWidth;

            $Div.scrollLeft(left);

        } );

    } );

}
```

The issue I am experiencing is that the DIV just won't move in Firefox.  In WebKit, it works as expected but all that happens in good ol' Mozilla is the `mousemove()` event gets fired.  I appreciate anyone's help.  Thank you.

Comment: The question title says, "not working in Safari", but the question itself seems to say that it's Firefox you're having problems with. Which is it?

Comment: Also you might want to describe exactly what's not working, and in what circumstances, etc.

Comment: That was incredibly stupid of me.  Thank you for pointing it out. I aplogize; I just woke up and am a bit... "tired."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remembered that Firefox requires an initial width for elements, and I had forgotten to again include the CSS I had for it after I first scrapped it.  That made all the difference.  Thanks anyway!